# Usage of functions across multiple include files

Tags: c

I am currently programming a µC in C, and for making things easier to read I separated all different connection functions (like SPI, TWI, GPIO) in separate function-/include-files. Thus I have now two files for all functions regarding TWI, two files for GPIO aso.. Now I want to use functions for SPI in my GPIO-functions, and the other way round. The easiest way would be to put simply all functions in a big file, but I want to avoid that in order to increase readibility. But I also can not include the GPIO-include file into the SPI-include file, after I want to use the functions from both files in the other file, too.
Thus, what is the best way to cross-use functions from two different files in C?

Comment: Why is it that you can't include files?

Comment: Headers can `#include` other headers, as long as you use [header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) properly.

Comment: If I include file A in file B in order to use the functions from A in B, and I include B again in A to use the functions from B in A, wouldn't that be a cross-reference (A in B in A etc.)? @dasblinkenlight: If I only include A in B, that would not be the problem, but if I include B in A again, wouldn't be that a problem?

Comment: No. That's the purpose of headers. Plus, if you only use the functions (and headers) in implementation, you don't even need to guard (As @dasblinkenlight pointed out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use headers:

#### a.h

```
int DoA();
int DoA2();
```

#### a.c

```
#include <b.h>
int DoA()
{
   return 1 + DoB();
}
int DoA2()
{
   return 2;
}
```

#### b.h

```
int DoB();
```

#### b.c

```
#include <a.h>
int DoB()
{
   return 1 + DoA2();
}
```

And with safe guards, you'd do:

#### a.h

```
#ifndef _INCL_A
#define _INCL_A

int DoA();
int DoA2();

#endif
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot that I can also put other .h-files into my function-file.